# Stuck in a bootloop after unexpected shutdown

Tags: boot, android-12

Is there any solution for corrupted /data/system/packages files (packages.xml, packages.list) after a unexpected shutdown, without the need of formatting the entire data partition?

My phone ran out of battery, and after that, it got stuck in a bootloop. Searching online, I found this post by the user sbrm1 ([Marshmallow not bootlooping, but not starting](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/157601)) with the same issue, and a possible solution posted by the user DvdGiessen. However, as reported in the comments, the solution posted by him no longer works on newer versions of Android (confirmed by me). Instead of generating new UIDs for the apps, the system is deleting all of them.

If anyone has any solution or suggestion for the problem and can assist me in resolving it, please leave a message.